# Difference sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show for a real sequence that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n - a_{n-2} = 0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{n} = 0$.

I see

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{n} + \frac{a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}}{n}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n - a_{n-2}) = 0,$$
but I realize if $\lim(x_n+ y_n) = 0$ we can't just conclude that $\lim x_n = 0$ and $\lim y_n= 0$ since those limits may not exist.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, $(x_n + x_{n-1}) - (x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}) = x_n - x_{n-2} \to 0$ implies that $(x_n + x_{n-1})/n \to 0$ by the Stolz-Cesaro theorem.

Taking $x_n = (-1)^n a_n$ we see that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{n}  = \lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n\frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{n}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^na_n + (-1)^{n-1}a_{n-1}}{n}= 0$$

since

$$(-1)^n a_n - (-1)^{n-2}a_{n-2} = (-1)^n (a_n - a_{n-2}) \to 0$$